# How to force symmetrical y-axis independently of the values drawn on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any option to force that the y-axis limits will always be symmetric around 0, independently of what is being drawn? E.g., my plot contents true limits are +1 and -0.8 (just an example, as I don't know the values in advance), but I would like matplotlib to force this to +1 and -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set limits of the y-axis manually:

```
plt.ylim(-1, 1)
```

If you want to adjust the limits automatically then you can try this:

```
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [-1, 7, -4])

# get y-axis limits of the plot
low, high = plt.ylim()
# find the new limits
bound = max(abs(low), abs(high))
# set new limits
plt.ylim(-bound, bound)
```

Comment: I gave just an an example with values. I don't know the values in advance.

Comment: plt.ylim(-1*max(abs(data)) * 1.1, max(abs(data)) * 1.1) ?